# Pattern for waiting for cache data to reload after a mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to figure out the right way of waiting for cache data to reload after a mutations is invoked. I would like to indicate the loading state until the data is fully reloaded. Currently I do something along the lines of:

```
const [start, startState] = useModifyDataMutation();
const [load loadState] = useGetDataQuery();
const onClick = async () => {
   await start();   
   await load();
};

return <LoadingButton onClick={onClick} 
                      loading={startState.isLoading || loadState.isFetching}>
       Start
       </LoadingButton>
```

The example does work for me but I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this without manually invoking data load and just rely on RTK's caching mechanism.

Comment: What you have looks correct to me. What exactly is the issue or problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the loading for any cache refresh (of this same request), RTKQ return has an `isFetching` property that you can use.